# Exception running TrueZip

Tags: java, truezip

I run a simple TrueZip code:

```
        TFile src = new TFile(path + file_to_add);  
        TFile dst = new TFile(path + outZipFile);  
        src.cp_rp(dst);
```

When i run the program the compiler throws (on the first line):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/schlichtherle/truezip/fs/FsSyncOption
```

I have truezip-file-7.4.3.jar and truezip-file-7.4.3-sources.jar files.

Am i missing jars or the problem may be something else?

Comment: can you show the source code?

Comment: @ILLA I added, it throws the exception on the first row

Comment: is there a compilation error or run time error ?

Comment: Please follow CPD/Nate's advice and update to the latest TrueZIP 7.6.4, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add **truezip-driver-file.jar** & **truezip-kernel.jar** according to Maven POM.

Comment: ... and truezip-driver-zip.jar, too.