# TrueZip: NoClassDefFoundError (but for shutdown hook only?)

Tags: java, maven, phantomjs, truezip

I have a project using PhantomJS. There is this plugin that will install it automatically:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.klieber</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <version>1.9.2</version>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <phantomjs.binary>${phantomjs.binary}</phantomjs.binary>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

And I get this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.665 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-07T13:27:39+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/175M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/schlichtherle/truezip/fs/FsSyncOptions
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncShutdownHook$Hook.run(FsSyncShutdownHook.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncOptions
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    ... 1 more
```

Adding these (according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403496/exception-running-truezip)):

```
<dependency>
  <!-- For the PhantomJS install plugin -->
  <groupId>de.schlichtherle.truezip</groupId>
  <artifactId>truezip-driver-file</artifactId>
  <version>7.7.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <!-- For the PhantomJS install plugin -->
  <groupId>de.schlichtherle.truezip</groupId>
  <artifactId>truezip-kernel</artifactId>
  <version>7.7.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <!-- For the PhantomJS install plugin -->
  <groupId>de.schlichtherle.truezip</groupId>
  <artifactId>truezip-driver-zip</artifactId>
  <version>7.7.9</version>
</dependency>
```

does not help (I get the same error message).

However:
The binary does gets downloaded and unzipped. The system property gets set. The tests that depend on this working run perfectly.

Also,

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep truezip
[INFO] +- de.schlichtherle.truezip:truezip-driver-file:jar:7.7.9:compile
[INFO] +- de.schlichtherle.truezip:truezip-kernel:jar:7.7.9:compile
[INFO] +- de.schlichtherle.truezip:truezip-driver-zip:jar:7.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.schlichtherle.truezip:truezip-swing:jar:7.7.9:compile
```

... so only one version is included.

Comment: Similar: [Alfresco Maven SDK - fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29511318/55075).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about PhantomJS, but as you figured the exception is thrown by a shutdown hook. This hook is a safety net which commits any pending changes to archive files by TrueZIP. You can easily remove it by calling `de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TVFS.umount()` just before the JVM terminates. Please wrap the call in a `finally`-block to ensure it gets called even if the application terminates with a Throwable.

Comment: Where exactly should I put that call, since it is a plugin that causes the exception to begin with?

Comment: I suppose you need to contact the plugin authors and tell them to add the missing call. It's missing on their end and there isn't much you could do about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute it via `java -jar` or your maven plugin calls a goal "outside" of provided scope, set the scope of the dependencies to `compile`.

Comment: Changing the scope did not remove the error. Tried both "compile" and "test".

Comment: This could also be a classpath issue (and I think that's what it really is...): how do you execute your goals/run app?

Comment: Interestingly, it happens only while running "mvn clean test" (which also downloads PhantomJS) and not while running "mvn test" (which then has PhantomJS already installed). It looks like there is a bug in the plugin itself, then.

Comment: There could be some configurations in the PhantomJS plugin itself that could not grab the desired dependencies..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing the java version from a IBM java 1.7 to an IBM java 1.8 (ibm_sdk_8.0.3.0) or Oracle java 1.8 (jdk_1.8.0.91_64). You can check your java version by typing `java -version` in a terminal or command prompt. OS = windows 10